# How to check which checkbox is checked in MVC using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 checkboxes and want to see that which checkbox is checked [vice-versa]. If `Group1` is checked then it should return `Group1:true` and vice versa.

```
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Group1, new { @class = "chk",@id= "Group1" })                
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Group2, new { @class = "chk", @id = "Group2"})               
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Group3, new { @class = "chk", @id = "Group3"})
```

Script

```
   $('.chk').change(function () {  
         var id = $(this).val();          
          $('#' + id).is(":checked");
        });
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're missing a closing ' after the .chk selector. Is that a copy error?

Comment: @RyanGibbs, It is fixed. Yes that was copy error.

Comment: `it should return Group1:true` Where do you want to return to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this all by using the $(this) object within your change listener. Here's a sample of how to do that:

```js
$('.chk').change(function () {          
    console.log($(this).attr('id') + ":" + $(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='Group1' class='chk'>
<input type='checkbox' id='Group2' class='chk'>
<input type='checkbox' id='Group3' class='chk'>
```

Here we grab the attribute 'id' to get the id of the control that was changed and then concatenate that with the result of .is(':checked'). Of course in my example I'm just console.logging the result, but you could return or do whatever you need to do with it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted more information on the state of the other checkboxes following the event, you could use (with comments):

```
$(function () {
    $(".chk").on("change", function () {
        var eventId = $(this).attr("id");
        // checked or unchecked for change event
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            console.log("=> " + eventId + " has been checked");
        } else {
            console.log("=> " + eventId + " has been unchecked");
        }

        // Iterate all checkboxes
        $.each($(".chk"), function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            if (id !== eventId) {
                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    console.log("=> " + id + " is checked");
                } else {
                    console.log("=> " + id + " is not checked");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```